# Getting 0x80070043 error when accessing Samba share from Windows 7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-7, samba, ubuntu-10.04

I created a Samba share on my new Ubuntu 10.04 machine. When I try to access it from a Windows 7 client, I get network error 0x80070043 (The network path not found). However, I get this error when I click on the share in the Windows Explorer, so it seems that Windows does find the path. I already enabled NTLMv1, disabled 128bit security and made sure that NetBIOS is running. I briefly disabled the Windows firewall, it didn't make a difference. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you ping the ip address of the ubuntu machine?

Comment: He can browse the shares on the machine, so he probably can :-p

Comment: Indeed I can ping the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error randomly, and was never completely able to understand what caused it, and/or to solve it. But it disappeared after upgrading to the latest Samba release (3.5.2), so it was probably due to some bug and/or lack of full support for Windows 7 client.

Which versione of Samba are you running?

Comment: It looks like I have 3.4.7 (2:3.4.7~dfsg-lubuntu3) and the Ubuntu package manager says that's the latest version. I guess I need to find a newer version...

Comment: You can download the source, compile and install it from the Samba web site (http://samba.org/), or you can look for already available binary packages (although it could be a little difficult to find them for Ubuntu); getting one for CentOS, which is the system I needed to install it on, was easy enough.

Comment: Upvoted, as I've found a lot of things in Samba can be fixed with an update...I've also found a number of things can break too ;)